# SQL bcp from SQL fie

Tags: sql, bcp

I save query in .sql file

I need to call this query using bcp and execute it . any idea how to do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you may want to use [sqlcmd](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773.aspx) for this rather than `bcp`.